# How do I set environment variables for system users in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish, environment-variables, glassfish-3

I have created a system user for my glassfishv3 installation that has no interactive shell, so no environment variables are set on this user when glassfish is started through asadmin.

I have tried to copy in the environment by using the following commands in my init script:

```
jhv=$(grep JAVA_HOME /etc/environment)
$jhv
export JAVA_HOME    
sudo -u glassfish -E $glassfishpath/asadmin start-domain domain1
```

Inside of asadmin I echo $JAVA_HOME which prints JAVA_HOME correctly.

Once glassfish starts up, I launch a web service with a single method that prints the environment key value pairs. JAVA_HOME is not among them. This causes a problem with any script executed by glassfish that requires JAVA_HOME.

So how do I set JAVA_HOME on a system user/glassfish environment so it persists once the java container is launched?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GF. What does "launch a web service" entail? Also, how are you printing the key value pairs?

Comment: @Ryan Stewart - glassfish being a java web container can host java web services. The applications (web services) that are known to the container are created or initialized when they are called by a client. As for your other question: Java has the ability to obtain the environments variables by using _System.getenv();_ which returns a map of environment entries. By iterating over the entries, you can append the key value pairs to a String, then return the String from the service as a response.

Comment: Sorry, I should've noted that I'm a Java developer, so I know the territory. I just haven't used GF. I work with Tomcat mostly. Unless GF is very different from other containers I've used, though, it wouldn't actually spawn a separate OS process for a web service, right? Are you just deploying a WAR?

Comment: what code do you use in you web service to get JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the solution woulbe be to add the `-E` flag to the sudo command. This flag tells sudo to maintain the current user's environment variables when dropping down into root access.

It looks like you are already using this flag though so I don't know what the problem is. It could be that the flag is failing silently in your script and you are not being notified. Have you tried running the script's command manual in a shell? What is the result/output?

Comment: The question says that JAVA_HOME is set correctly in the asadmin script, which is being run by sudo. That means the -E is working, but the value is getting lost somewhere.